# Meaning of regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Is the meaning of this regex: `(\d+).*?` - group a set of numbers, then take whatever that comes after (only one occurance of it at maximum, except a newline)?

Is there a difference in: `(\d+) and [\d]+`?

Comment: the first is a group, the second is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as many digits as possible (at least `1`), then take the smallest amount of characters as possible (except newline). The non greedy qualifier (`?`) doesn't really help unless you have the rest of your pattern following it, otherwise it will just match as little as possible, in this case, always `0`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'(\d+).*?', '123').group()
'123'
>>> re.match(r'(\d+).*?', '123abc').group()
'123'
```

The difference between `(\d+)` and `[\d]+` is the fact that the former groups and the latter doesn't. `([\d]+)` would however be equivalent.

```
>>> re.match(r'(\d+)', '123abc').groups()
('123',)
>>> re.match(r'[\d]+', '123abc').groups()
()
```

Comment: this is the expression: `(\d+).*?(\S*)`, is it match atleast one occurance of any non-white char (in a group), so if I have "5000 balls", `5000` will be in group1 and `[whitespace]balls` in group(2)?

Comment: @JamesHallen try it for yourself

Comment: @JamesHallen Why don't you try it? It gives `('5000', '')`. `.*?` matches the empty string because it is not greedy, and `\S*` matches the empty string because next character is a space.

Comment: I'm confused, `.*` should match the white space between "5000" and "balls", then shouldn't `?(\S*)` match "balls"?

Comment: @JamesHallen `.*?` would match the empty space if it had to -- when the regex as a whole would otherwise fail. For example, in `(\d+).*?(\S+)` it would have to match the space so that `\S+` is able to match something.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d)+  One or more occurance of digits, 
.* followed by any characters,
? lazy operator i.e. return the minimum match.
```

Comment: can someone please decrypte this pattern? \d+(?:\.\d*)  ?

Answer (score 0):

group1 will be at least one number and group0 will contain group1 and maybe other characters but not necessarily.

edit to answer the edited question: AFAIK there should be no difference in the matching between those 2 other than the grouping.